# How to run commands without having access to shell

Tags: magento-2.1

I am customizing a Magento 2 theme, I am a little bit confused that after changing anything in coding or changes in CSS I have to run some command as suggested

For this each time I have to ask system administrator to run the command as I have no access to shell

like `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command

Is there any other way to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

When you are working with M2 you must need to deal with commands.

You will need to ask your system administrator to create one user group with some restrictions so you can use that group to run commands and it can not be used as root user.

Another way use php `shell_exec` function to run your commands. You can create one script on root and run your command with `shell_exec`. You can run your file in browser.

For more details check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your css and js in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/Your_Theme/en_US/css` and `pub/static/frontend/Magento/Your_Theme/en_US/js`. This way you won't need to run `setup:static-content:deploy` command on every changes you make in css or js. But remember one thing that whenever someone runs a `setup:upgrade` command, you will lost your css and js from **pub** directory. For this, you have to copy all css, js, images and fonts from **pub** folder to your theme's **web** folder